# Querying a hibernate entity with two one-to-many collections

Tags: java, hibernate

I am selecting a number (x) of entities Foo using Hibernate.  Each foo has one-to-many collections bar and baz that are set to lazy fetching.  I will need to populate bar and baz for each foo, so I definitely do not want a subselect to be issued per collection (2 * x + 1 selects).

However, I also don't necessarily want to setFetchMode(FetchMode.JOIN) on both because this will return the Cartesian product (bar x baz).  Also, if I define foo and bar as Lists, I will receive duplicate items.  I can issue two Criterias:

```
List<Foo> foos;
foo = session.createCriteria(Foo.class).setFetchMode("bar", FetchMode.JOIN).list();
foo = session.createCriteria(Foo.class).setFetchMode("baz", FetchMode.JOIN).list();
```

but the code looks rather sloppy.  It looks like the first query was unnecessary.  Is there a neater way to fetch both bar and baz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd dump the criteria and use HQL for this.

```
String hql = "select new list(foo.bar, foo.baz) from Foo foo";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List list = query.list;
Bar bar = list.get(0);
Baz baz = list.get(1);
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: What is foo has additional members (non-collections) that I would like?  Would you select them individually too?

Comment: You could, you could also say select foo.name, new list(foo.bar, foo.baz) ... I think my query actually returns a list of lists. But you can play with it. You can also return maps. "select new map( max(bodyWeight) as max, min(bodyWeight) as min, count(*) as n ). etc. Have fun.
from Cat cat" Anything that has a constructor that matches.

Comment: I'm sticking with the two Criteria queries for now but thanks for the excellent answer ;-)